# String operations in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a string `"011100011"`.
Now I need to find another string by adding the adjacent digits of this string, like the output string should be `"123210122"`.

How do I split each characters in the string and manipulate them?

The method that I thought was to convert the string to integer using Parsing and splitting each character using modulus or something and performing operations on them.

But can you suggest some simpler methods?

Comment: I don't understand your example:  011100011 + 011100011 = 22200022.
And your example answer has a 3 in it.  By adding adjacent digits, I can only get a maximum of 2 in any position.  Please clarify your example, then I will try to answer.

Comment: res[0] = 0+1; res[1] = 0+1+1; res[2] = 1+1+1; res[3] = 1+1+0; etc

Comment: @Dahlbyk - your explanation doesn't clarify the original question for me, I'm afraid. What does adjeacnet digits mean - 2 adjacent digits, or 3? - best result that I can come up with is 12210012 - the result will always be one character shorter than the input.

Comment: @belugabob: here's how I understood it: every digit in the output string should be the sum of that digit and its two adjacent digits (in the input string).

Comment: @Pragadheesh - I think a little more explanation about the problem domain is due - I suspect that a different data type may be an answer to the problem.

Comment: @Martin - thanks, that makes more sense now. I suppose the coffee hasn't kicked in yet ;-) I'm still intrigued about the problem domain - even more so, now that I've been enlightened by Martin.

Comment: @all - sorry for not clearly specifying my problem. Martin came up with the right thing. Adjacent digits meant the digits on either side. But for the digits on extremity, it can have only one adjacent digit. hope its clear.

Comment: Good grief dear fellow: what on EARTH is your teacher smoking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses some LINQ plus dahlbyk's idea:

```
string input = "011100011";

// add a 0 at the start and end to make the loop simpler
input = "0" + input + "0"; 

var integers = (from c in input.ToCharArray() select (int)(c-'0'));
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length-2; i++)
{
    output += integers.Skip(i).Take(3).Sum();
}

// output is now "123210122"
```

Please note:

- the code is not optimized. E.g. you might want to use a StringBuilder in the for loop.
- What should happen if you have a '9' in the input string -> this might result in two digits in the output string.

Comment: Or 2 adjacent values which add up to more than 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the string to a character array and then subtract `'0'` from the `char` values to retrieve an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "011100011";
int current;

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i ++)
{
  current = int.Parse(input[i]);

  // do something with current...
}
```